# Try to avoid joining a large table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql-server.I have a table looks like:

```
Name    timestamp                var1    
Bill    2015-02-05 10:10:10       x1
Bill    2015-02-05 10:10:11       x2
...
Jim     2015-02-05 10:10:10       y1
Jim     2015-02-05 10:10:11       y2
...
John    2015-02-05 10:10:10       z1
John    2015-02-05 10:10:11       z2
```

The table is very large say 1 million rows and the timestamp is updated every second. I want to select the people whose var1 value change delta var1 in any one minute (i.e. x61-x1 or x62-x2, etc) is between 5-7. Here is my code with joining.

```
declare @duration int
 set @duration = 60

    SELECT a.name,
          a.var1-b.var1 AS change
 From Table1  a
 inner join Table1 b
   on a.name = b.name
   and a.timestamp = b.timestamp +  @duration
 Where change between 5 and 7
```

However, I know there are two major problems.

1. Timestamp can't be compared like this. Is there any way to fix it please?
2. My table is too large. If joining each time, it will take too long to run. Any idea to avoid that please?

Comment: Do you have an index for Name and timestamp on your table? If not, add one.

Comment: 1 million rows is not "very large" ;)

Comment: I don't understand quite well what you are trying to achieve. You want to select all people that got their timestamp updated relatively close to each other (within some delta)?

Comment: store the timestamp as an integer (as well as human readable), arithmetic becomes faster. Oh, and use an index.

Comment: Thank you all for reply. May I ask how to add index to Name and timestamp please?

Comment: [TSQL `Create Index`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `@duration` is a number of minutes that join should look like

```
....
and a.timestamp = DATEADD(mi,@duration,b.timestamp)
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the dateadd function

Answer (score 1):

If you're in SQL Server 2012 or newer you can solve this by using LAG() -window function, since with that you can compare the value of the row to the previous one, and if you order them properly, that's the one you're interested in.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

It should probably be possible to adjust "Gaps and Islands" problem solutions to this one too.

Edit, found the post by Itzik Ben-Gan I remember reading earlier, this belongs to the "special islands" category:

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```
declare @duration int
set @duration = 60

SELECT 
     a.name,
     (SELECT TOP (1) a.var1-b.var1 
      FROM  Table1 b  
      WHERE a.name = b.name
          and a.timestamp = DATEADD(second, @duration , b.timestamp)
          AND  (a.var1-b.var1) between 5 and 7) As Change
FROM
    Table1 AS a
```

I hope that might occur somewhat helpful.